# Bind LiveData<String> to TextView

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

I'm trying to bind LiveData to the value of a TextView.

I successfully set the viewmodel as a variable, but the TextView doesn't show any text.

This is my XML-Code:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='@{viewmodel.getText("TI_001")}'/>
```

viewmodel.getText(id) returns LiveData. When I try this with a function that simply returns a random String, the binding works properly and the TextView is filled.

This is my getText method:

```
public LiveData<String> getText(String id){
    return textDao.findById(id);
}
```

This is the findById-method:

```
@Query("SELECT text.text FROM text WHERE text.id LIKE :id")
LiveData<String> findById(String id);
```

Can anybody help me make this binding working?

**UPDATE:**

In my fragment I'm setting the livecycleowner as following:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    return mBinding.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the getText function to your question please.

Comment: I edited my question and included the getText method.

Comment: what is `textDao.findById(id);` doing?

Comment: @lelloman edited my post.

Comment: Ok so 2 questions: 1) If you try the query without data binding does it return something? 2) Are you sure you're observing the live data? What happens if you set the text on the TextView from a String property of the ViewModel, do you see the text then?

Comment: 1. Yes, the expected value is returned.
2. In that case, the String value is displayed.

Comment: Uhm I was expecting one of the 2 not to work...then I'm sorry but I have no idea :D

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely that you are not telling your data binding which lifecycle you want to attach to:

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(yourLifeCycleOwner)
```

You need to do this if you intend to use `LiveData` as a data binding.

Official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#setlifecycleowner

Comment: I'm actually already doing that. Updated my question. P.S.: Sorry for the long inactivity.